# Multivariable Delta Epsilon Proof $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^4}$ --- looking for a hint

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

I have the limit
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^4},$$
and would like to show with an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof that it is zero. I know with a situation like
$$\left|\frac{x^4y}{x^4+y^4}\right|\leq y$$ 
or something similar, but I can't find a way to do the same thing here, as no single term in the numerator is of sufficient degree, although I think I could get this with a small hint.

Comment: You can use $2ab \leqslant a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: Or this is one place a polar coordinates substitution can work really nicely, as $|\cos^3\theta\sin^2\theta|\le 1$ (we could get a better upper bound, but why bother?).

Comment: Thanks guys, the first hint especially was quite helpful. Feeling rather silly now...

Comment: @Imbilio I suggest you answer your own question so this doesn't come up as unanswered.

Comment: To see a proof based on Daniel Fischer's hint, see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822811/continuity-of-fracx3y2x4y4-at-0-0/1822821#1822821) to a duplicate question.

Comment: Two more closely related questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856098/proving-fracx3y2x4y4-is-continuous and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822811/continuity-of-fracx3y2x4y4-at-0-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hint:

$$L=\lim_{(x,\: y)\to (0,\: 0)}\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^4}=\lim_{(x,\: y)\to (0,\: 0)}\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}\: .x$$

Because $$\left|\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}\right|\leq\frac{1}{2}\to L=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=\max (|x|,|y|).$ Then $$|x^3 y^2|\leq z^5.$$ And for $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$ we have $x^4+y^4\geq z^4>0$, implying  $$0<1/(x^4+y^4)\leq 1/z^4 .$$ So for $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$ we have $$|(x^3 y^2)/(x^4+y^4|\leq z^5(1/z^4)=z.$$