# Prove $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 y^3}{x^4 + y^4} =0$ without $\varepsilon - \delta$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Unlike [Multivariable Delta Epsilon Proof $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^4}$ --- looking for a hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511518/multivariable-delta-epsilon-proof-lim-x-y-to0-0-fracx3y2x4y4) I would like to avoid the $\varepsilon - \delta$ criterium.

> Prove $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 y^3}{x^4 + y^4} =0 \,.$$

Approaching this limit from $y=0$, $x=0$, $y=x$, $y=x^2$ etcetera all yields 0 as value, so my proposal is that this limit is indeed 0.

I have been able to solve most similar limits so far by finding some convergent upper bound for the absolute limit, but with this one the difference between the numerator and the denominator is so small I can't find anything to fit inbetween. For example, $(x,y)\to(0,0)$,
$$ \left| \frac{x^2 y}{x^2 + y^2} \right| \le \left| \frac{(x^2 + y^2)y}{x^2 + y^2} \right| \to 0 \,. $$

Also, [Continuity of $\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^4}$ at $(0,0)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822811/continuity-of-fracx3y2x4y4-at-0-0) and [Proving $ \frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^4}$ is continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856098/proving-fracx3y2x4y4-is-continuous) contain some helpful hints.

Comment: @Αδριανός Thanks for the different suggestion! It seems to work fine, at least it's a systematic way, which is great!

Comment: @Αδριανός I think you accidentally left out the factor $r$ in the polar formulas.

Comment: @StackTD You're right, I even read over that haha.

Comment: Hard to let $r \to 0$ when there is no $r$ ;o).

Comment: Ah right sorry about that; that would certainly make a difference!

Comment: I believe switching to polar coordinates also works and is quite effective. Use the normal substitutions $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ then change the limit to the single variable one as $r$ goes to $0$. Note that it doesn't matter how you approach the origin, so the theta values don't matter to a certain extent under the limit.

Comment: @StackTD That is quite important to the limit ;) Here is the amended comment.

Comment: Through [this index](https://mathindex.wordpress.com/multivariable-limits-at-the-origin/) I found [another question about the same limit](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511518/multivariable-delta-epsilon-proof-lim-x-y-to0-0-fracx3y2x4y4). However, the other question specifically asks for $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof.

Comment: These two questions are very closely related, too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822811/continuity-of-fracx3y2x4y4-at-0-0 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856098/proving-fracx3y2x4y4-is-continuous

Comment: @MartinSleziak Oh, that's a useful index! The other question about the same limit is indeed not really the same, but the hints given would have made me able to solve this one, the same with the other two questions mentioned. I am pretty curious why those other questions didn't came up in the first two pages on google... A google search just brings me back to my own question. For that reason I'll not delete the question but edit it a little, I hope that's the right thing to do.

Comment: See also the general case at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66226/multivariable-limit-proof-lim-x-y-rightarrow-0-0-frac-leftx-righta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have:
$$(x^2-y^2)^2 \ge 0 \Rightarrow x^4+y^4 \ge 2x^2y^2$$
So also:
$$x^2y^2 \le x^4+y^4$$
Which means:
$$\left| \frac{x^2y^3}{x^4+y^4} \right| \le \left| \frac{x^2y^3}{x^2y^2} \right| = |y|$$

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was searching for! Always seems to simple in hindsight... @GFauxPas I googled it, it seems to be the same written in a little different form.

Comment: You're welcome; the inequality $x^4+y^4 \ge 2x^2y^2$ often comes in handy with these kind of problems.

Answer (score 3):

In polar coordinates the expression is

$$r\frac{\cos^2t\sin^3t}{\cos^4 t + \sin^4 t}.$$

The denominator in this fraction has a positive minimum; thus the fraction is a bounded function of $t,$ and the $r$ in front guarantees a limit of $0.$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1**: $$\frac{x^2 y^3}{x^4+y^4}=\frac{y}{(x/y)^2+(y/x)^2}. $$

**Hint 2**: $f(u)=u^2+u^{-2}$ has an absolute minimum.

Comment: I agree that it works, but I like StackTD's answer better because I don't know how I could have thought of this...

Comment: @PHPirate: I just divided top and bottom by $x^2y^2$. Hadn't seen the other answer, in fact this is another way to get the same inequality.

Comment: I saw that, I was talking about thinking of the absolute minimum of $u^2 + u^{-2}$ ;)

Comment: @PHPirate: Oh. Well, the function is continuous on its domain, positive and goes to $\infty$ as $x\to0,\pm\infty$, hence it can be expected. :)